# C# facebook sdk post animated gif

Tags: c#, facebook, gif, animated-gif, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to develop an application for posting animated gifs directly to a facebook wall of a logged user.

Everything works fine with static images, but when I try to upload animated gif, only first frame is shown on a user wall...

My code is:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(printfile));
FacebookMediaObject facebookUploader = new FacebookMediaObject { FileName = file.FullName, ContentType = "image/gif" };
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
facebookUploader.SetValue(bytes);
var postInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postInfo.Add("image", facebookUploader);
FBClient.Post("/me/photos", postInfo);
```

What am I doing wrong? I have done a little searching in this topic, I'm know that in the past it wasn't even possible to publish animated gifs on facebook, but now I can see there is a lot of animated gifs on facebook, so it's seems to me it's possible now...

Unfortunately, facebook c# sdk is a third party software and I cant find a good documentation for it. I know that it is somewhere in the internet, but I can't find it... I would be very gratefull if you could help me find a good one.

I would appreciate every clue and answer.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: a workaround for your problem would be to upload it on an external server or your webserver then make a fb post with the link and without a title of the gif

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I'm wondering if is there any other way to do this. The best solution for me would be posting directly - like the static images